# Why do my Binary Search Tree nodes break?

Tags: c

I need to make a linked list out of BST roots. Every node from the list has its corresponding root of the BST. I dont know where the problem is but it has something to do with the nodes of the BST being overwritten. For example if i input: 10 11 19 in the BST the right node of the root (10) will point to 19 and not 11.

The program works like this: The add function is called only twice which adds a root of the BST and its information for the first time, and for the second call you create a new node for the linked list and a new root for the BST as well as its information.

Type BST represents a node of a BST where info is an integer.
Type LIST represents a node of a linked list of BST's.

I need to write a function add which ads a node to the end of the linked list, whereas the user needs to input data of every node of the BST until he exits.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct BST
{
    int info;
    struct BST * left, * right;
}BST;

typedef struct LIST
{
    BST * root;
    struct LIST * next;
}LIST;

BST * new_node(int info)
{
    BST * new = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
    new->info = info;
    return new;
}

BST * add_node(BST * root, int info)
{
    if(root == NULL) return new_node(info);
    if(info < root->info) root->left = add_node(root->left, info);
    else if(info >= root->info) root->right = add_node(root->right, info);
}

LIST * add(LIST ** head)
{
    if((* head)->root == NULL)
    {
        BST * BTreeNode = NULL;
        BTreeNode = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
        (* head)->root = BTreeNode;
        printf("Enter tree root: \n");
        int n_root;
        scanf("%d", &n_root);
        BTreeNode->info = n_root;
        char character;
        do
        {
            printf("Add [A], exit [E]: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &character);
            if(character == 'A')
            {
                printf("Enter data: ");
                int temp;
                scanf("%d", &temp);
                add_node(BTreeNode, temp);

            }
        }while(character != 'E');
    }
    else
    {
        LIST * temp = NULL;
        temp = * head;
        for(; temp->next; temp = temp->next);
        LIST * new = NULL;
        new = calloc(1, sizeof(LIST));
        temp->next = new;

        BST * BTreeNode = NULL;
        BTreeNode = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
        new->root = BTreeNode;
        printf("Enter tree root: \n");
        int n_root;
        scanf("%d", &n_root);
        BTreeNode->info = n_root;
        char character;
        do
        {
            printf("Add [A], exit [E]: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &character);
            if(character == 'A')
            {
                printf("Enter data: ");
                int temp;
                scanf("%d", &temp);
                add_node(BTreeNode, temp);
            }
        }while(character != 'E');
    }
}

void delete_tree(BST * root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete_tree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

void clean_up(LIST ** head)
{
    while(* head)
    {
        LIST * temp = NULL;
        temp = (* head)->next;
        delete_tree((* head)->root);
        free(* head);
        * head = temp;
    }
}

void inorder(BST * root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->info);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void write(LIST * head)
{
    int counter = 1;
    LIST * temp = NULL;
    temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("\nInfo of %d. tree: ", counter++);
        inorder(temp->root);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LIST * head = NULL;
    head = calloc(1, sizeof(LIST));
    add(&head);
    add(&head);
    write(head);
    clean_up(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the same empty node twice? You should review the docs on `calloc`. It initializes every byte of the data block to zero, so you don't have to do things like `head->next = NULL;`.  `node` and `node_t` is confusing, try using `ListNode` and `BTreeNode` or anything more appropriate for purpose than just `node`. Normally, one would expect an interface that takes values as inputs, not implementation details, such as nodes of various types.

Comment: You should separate concerns. User I/O should not be mixed in with data structure manipulation.  Create and test linked list code and BST code separately, then write the program that combines their use to solve whatever problem it is you are trying to solve.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: This is an obvious homework assignment. You should [edit] your post to include the exact text of the homework assignment. Then we can all give you better guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt change the root node of the BST when i was passing it to the function add_node and returning it contained in the loop.
Here is a working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct BST
{
    int info;
    struct BST * left, * right;
}BST;

typedef struct LIST
{
    BST * root;
    struct LIST * next;
}LIST;

BST * new_node(int info)
{
    BST * new = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
    new->info = info;
    return new;
}

BST * add_node(BST * root, int info)
{
    if(root == NULL) return new_node(info);
    if(info < root->info) root->left = add_node(root->left, info);
    else if(info >= root->info) root->right = add_node(root->right, info);
    return root;
}

LIST * add(LIST ** head)
{
    if((* head)->root == NULL)
    {
        BST * BTreeNode = NULL;
        BTreeNode = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
        (* head)->root = BTreeNode;
        printf("Enter tree root: \n");
        int n_root;
        scanf("%d", &n_root);
        BTreeNode->info = n_root;
        char character;
        do
        {
            printf("Add [A], exit [E]: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &character);
            if(character == 'A')
            {
                printf("Enter data: ");
                int temp;
                scanf("%d", &temp);
                BTreeNode = add_node(BTreeNode, temp);
            }
        }while(character != 'E');
    }
    else
    {
        LIST * temp = NULL;
        temp = * head;
        for(; temp->next; temp = temp->next);
        LIST * new = NULL;
        new = calloc(1, sizeof(LIST));
        temp->next = new;

        BST * BTreeNode = NULL;
        BTreeNode = calloc(1, sizeof(BST));
        new->root = BTreeNode;
        printf("Enter tree root: \n");
        int n_root;
        scanf("%d", &n_root);
        BTreeNode->info = n_root;
        char character;
        do
        {
            printf("Add [A], exit [E]: ");
            scanf("\n%c", &character);
            if(character == 'A')
            {
                printf("Enter data: ");
                int temp;
                scanf("%d", &temp);
                BTreeNode = add_node(BTreeNode, temp);
            }
        }while(character != 'E');
    }
}

void delete_tree(BST * root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        delete_tree(root->left);
        delete_tree(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}

void clean_up(LIST ** head)
{
    while(* head)
    {
        LIST * temp = NULL;
        temp = (* head)->next;
        delete_tree((* head)->root);
        free(* head);
        * head = temp;
    }
}

void inorder(BST * root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->info);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

void write(LIST * head)
{
    int counter = 1;
    LIST * temp = NULL;
    temp = head;
    while(temp)
    {
        printf("\nInfo of %d. tree: ", counter++);
        inorder(temp->root);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LIST * head = NULL;
    head = calloc(1, sizeof(LIST));
    add(&head);
    add(&head);
    write(head);
    clean_up(&head);
    return 0;
}
```